# Even though x still y sentence pattern

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I am aware of 雖然 being used as although, however, I am not sure if it is appropriate for the following example situations.

**English examples:**

*Even though* he wore a helmet, he *still* suffered a serious concussion.

*Even though* she got everything she wanted for her birthday, she *still* acted like a brat.

*Even though* we installed the best security system, the thieves *still* found a way inside.

**Form:**

*Even though* [condition x which would usually prevent result y], [subject] *still* [result y].

Can "雖然 x 但是 y" be used when the conditions are extreme like this?

If not, what form would you recommend?

Comment: Seem fine to me, why do you think they aren't appropriate?

Comment: I just consulted with a native speaker, they said 雖然 was not appropriate and recommended "即使 x 還是 y", for my example situations, "即使 x 仍然 y", for: "Even though his girlfriend doesn't love him, he still loves her," and also something with 儘管, however I'm not sure I understood the nuance of the explanation due to the fact that it was in Chinese.

Comment: searching web with e。g。＂翻译 even though 。。。still
＂besides google translate （which does not provide example sentences） yields plenty of example sentences，in fact results ２ －－ ８ all have example sentences (often more than 1) including ＂still＂

Comment: Those works,all  statements are totally right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I'm a native Chinese speaker from Mainland China. People from other Chinese-speaking regions or countries may feel different from me.)

**`雖然 x 但是 y` sounds fine to me for all your examples.**

However, to me the turn embedded in `儘管 x 但是 y` sounds a little bit stronger than that in `雖然 x 但是 y`. That's why when the conditions are very extreme, `儘管 x 但是 y` sounds more natural to me.

**I think neither `即使 x 還是 y` nor `即使 x 仍然 y` is appropriate for your examples.**

A critical difference between a. `儘管 x 但是 y`, `雖然 x 但是 y` and b. `即使 x 還是 y`, `即使 x 仍然 y`:

For group a, x is a statement that the speaker believes to be true, while for group b, x is only a supposition (usually an extreme one).

> e.g.
>
> **儘管**我們安裝了最好的安防系統，賊還是**進來了**。
>
> → The speaker believes that the system has been installed and some
>   thief or thieves have found a way inside.
>
> **即使**我們安裝了最好的安防系統，賊還是**會進來的**。
>
> → The speaker makes a supposition that (EVEN IF) we installed the best
>   security system, and he shows that he believes that still some thief
>   or thieves will find a way inside.

**Since for group b, x is only a supposition, the sentence below will sound weird:**

> **即使**我們安裝了最好的安防系統，賊還是**進來了**。
>
> → The speaker makes **a supposition** that (EVEN IF) we installed the
>   best security system, and he shows that he believes that some thief or
>   thieves **have already** found a way inside.